# Coloring question numbers in the exam document class

Tags: color, exam

I am working with the exam documentclass. How can I color the question numbers. That is, I want some question numbers to appear red. How would I go about it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you want.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\color{red}\thequestion.}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question Question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Scott Seidman noted that it changes *all* questions.
If you want to change only one question number, you can use:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{color}

\let\oldquestionlabel=\questionlabel

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\color{red}\thequestion.}
    \question Question 1
    \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\oldquestionlabel}
    \question Question 2
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does *all* the question numbers.  The question is how to do *some* of them

Comment: You are right, see the edited answer